# How to get data from DataFrame/Matplot

Tags: python, pandas

I've been trying to learn Python as of late and have began a personal project that essentially is a simple stock trader bot. I'm trying to implement a simple Bollinger Band want to get the Bollinger Bands' values when it is the current date. I currently have run into an issue of trying to pull the stock price (y-value) from the two plots (orange and green) when I have the x-value (current date). I was looking for ways to do this but most implement numpy as the points are already in an x-value list and a y-value list.

Any help is appreciated! (Attached below is the graph and the code for printing the graphs)

[Graphs]
[image]

[Code]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python has a library that provides a rich set of features as technical indicators. The official reference can be found [here](https://mrjbq7.github.io/ta-lib/) The library also calculates Bollinger Bands, and returns three arrays of results that can be plotted on a graph to get what you want.

```
# !pip install yfinance
# !wget https://launchpad.net/~mario-mariomedina/+archive/ubuntu/talib/+files/libta-lib0_0.4.0-oneiric1_amd64.deb -qO libta.deb
# !wget https://launchpad.net/~mario-mariomedina/+archive/ubuntu/talib/+files/ta-lib0-dev_0.4.0-oneiric1_amd64.deb -qO ta.deb
# !dpkg -i libta.deb ta.deb
# !pip install ta-lib
import talib
import yfinance as yf
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

begin = datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=100)
finish = datetime.datetime.today()
stockinfo = yf.download("AAPL", start=begin, end=finish)

stockinfo['20 Day MA'] = stockinfo['Adj Close'].rolling(window=20).mean()
stockinfo['20 Day STD'] = stockinfo['Adj Close'].rolling(window=20).std()
stockinfo['Upper_bband'] = stockinfo['20 Day MA'] + (stockinfo['20 Day STD'] * 1.5)
stockinfo['Lower_bband'] = stockinfo['20 Day MA'] - (stockinfo['20 Day STD'] * 1.5)

bbands = talib.BBANDS(np.array(stockinfo['Adj Close']))

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=(12.5, 5))
plt.plot(stockinfo.index, stockinfo['20 Day MA'], label='20 Day MA')
plt.plot(stockinfo.index, stockinfo['Upper_bband'], label='upper_bband')
plt.plot(stockinfo.index, stockinfo['Lower_bband'], label='lower_bband')
plt.plot(stockinfo.index, bbands[0], label='bband1')
plt.plot(stockinfo.index, bbands[1], label='bband2')
plt.plot(stockinfo.index, bbands[2], label='bband3')

plt.title('AAPL: 20 Day Bollinger Band')
plt.xlabel(begin.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + '-' + finish.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
plt.ylabel('Price (in USD)')
plt.legend(loc='upper left')

plt.show()
```

[image]